# Time series plot range

Tags: r, plot, xts

Hi am ploting a xts object: 
[image]

And I would like to extend the xlim til 30-february because I want to add the prediction from an Arima model:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
pred <- predict(try2, n.ahead = 1,se.fit=T)
lim_sup <- pred$pred + 1.96 * pred$se
lim_inf <- pred$pred - 1.96 * pred$se
plot(heat["1996-02-01 00:00/1996-02-16 04:00"],type="l",main="Cross Validation")
points(exp(pred$pred),col="blue",lwd=2)
points(exp(lim_sup),lwd=2,col="green")
points(exp(lim_inf),lwd=2,col="green")
```

But I can not see any lines in the plot. Could you give me some recommendation?

The heat time series looks like this

```
                     HC.f
1996-02-01 00:00:00 1437.000
1996-02-01 01:00:00 1441.600
1996-02-01 02:00:00 1489.300
1996-02-01 03:00:00 1501.300
1996-02-01 04:00:00 1568.400
1996-02-01 05:00:00 1629.400
```

While the predictions for one hour step:

```
pred$pred
Time Series:
Start = 3002 
End  = 3002 
Frequency = 1 
[1] 7.480588
```

Comment: Could you provide `try2` and `heat` so we can give it a try? There is probably something wrong with your indexing on `heat`.

Comment: February 30 doesn't exist, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Merge your actual and prediction objects before plotting.  Then you will have one time series over the full desired time period.

```
library(xts)
set.seed(21)
x <- xts(rnorm(10),Sys.Date()-10:1)
y <- xts(rnorm(3),Sys.Date()+0:2)
z <- merge(x,y)
plot(z[,1], ylim=range(z,na.rm=TRUE))
lines(z[,2],col='red')
```