# R setting xlim in xts plot

Tags: r, plot, xts

I am trying to expand the X-axis of my time series plot to be prepared for adding new data into the plot later on. However, whatever I try I get the **Error in plot.window(...) : invalid 'xlim' value** error.

Here is a minimal code snippet:

Data construction:

```
time_series <- xts(rnorm(100),seq(as.POSIXct("2012-01-01 00:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2012-01-05 03:00:00"), by="hour"))
```

Plotting:

```
plot(time_series, type='l');
```

The result is, as expected, a nice time series plot.

Now, I wanted to expand the x-axis and I tried:

```
xlim <- seq(as.POSIXct("2012-01-01 00:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2012-01-06 03:00:00"), by="hour")
plot <- (time_series, xlim = xlim, type='l')
```

but this is not working but results in **Error in plot.window(...) : invalid 'xlim' value**.

Trying the following results in the same error:

```
xlim <- c(as.POSIXct("2012-01-01 00:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2012-01-05 00:00:00"))
```

From the documentation I know that xlim has to be numeric and can be set like xlim = c(0,100) but how does it work when using xts data?

**Edit**: I know that this question is similar to the question [Time series plot range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16164989/time-series-plot-range?rq=1). However, as I don't know the data that needs to be plotted in the future I am interested in this particular solution.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `plot.xts`, but `xlim` in base graphics is normally a vector with exactly two values (min and max) and not a sequence.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I also tried a vector including mix max POSIXct values. Sorry, I will add this to my question.

Comment: In general, I suggest using `plot.zoo` or `xtsExtra::plot.xts`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this:

```
plot(time_series, type='l',
     xlim=as.POSIXct(c("2012-01-01 00:00:00","2012-01-06 03:00:00")))
```

Comment: Okay, it definitely works. I am not sure why I was convinced it won't - sorry. Unfortunately, axis label seems to be missing in the plot but that's something I can live with.

Answer (score 0):

Or you make a subset in xts before: df2.xts<-df.xts["2012-01-01/2012-02-01"] and Then plot(df2.xts).